# Leak Memory in large Form - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, memory-leaks

I’m testing my app because a Leak memmory problem. My app is about a large Form with (134 textformfield). At the begining, it works very good but when i want to use the form for the tenth time, it gets heavy and takes longer to save data in sqlite. But when i restart the app, it storage data in sqlite very faster again. I’m use Provider to manage states and i need to destroy or “dispose” only widgets which are part of the form. But i don’t need to dispose my providers because i’m going to use the form  200 times more.

Acoording to the image (usage 1) in firts time my form builds it creates 23 widgets. When i use the form for the fifth time, it acumulates widgets equivalent to 5 forms (usage 5). That’s why i want to eliminate Form widgets afeter use and not my provider. Even when i see memory usage it gets heavier for phone.

Any recomendation to reduce or destruct widgets properly. Thanks in advance.

PDT1: While i fill my Form as much heavier is the memory the message appers to me:

```
"Background concurrent copying GC freed 22384(2152KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 2318 KB/4637 KB, paused 578 us total 131.578ms"
```

PDT 2: I made a custom widget to build my Form. I pass the parameter `lista` which builds the Form using two loop FOR.

```
class WidgetArmarCartilla extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<dynamic> lista;
  
  const WidgetArmarCartilla({
    Key? key, 
    required this.lista, 
    }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final infoAlmacenarValCart= Provider.of<InfoAlmacenarValCartProvider>(context,listen: true);

    return Form(
      key: this.key,
      child: Column(
        children:<Widget>[
        for(var i=0;i<this.lista[0].length;i++)
          Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(accentColor: globalColor,dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
            child: ExpansionTile (
              collapsedTextColor: Colors.black,
              textColor: globalColor,
              iconColor: globalColor,
              collapsedIconColor: globalColor,
              title: Text ("${this.lista[0][i]}",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 18),),
              children: <Widget>[
                    for(var j=0;j<this.lista[1][i].length;j++)
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  child: ListTile (
                    //leading: SizedBox(width: 0,),
                    title: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Text("    "),
                          Expanded(child: Text ("${this.lista[1][i][j]}",overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,maxLines: 2,))
                        ],
                      )
                      ),
                    trailing: Container(
                      height: 45,
                      width:90,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(counterText: ""),
                        maxLength: 7,
                        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                        cursorColor: globalColor,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        initialValue: (infoAlmacenarValCart.getAndgrabarEnDb(this.lista[2][i][j])!=null)?infoAlmacenarValCart.getAndgrabarEnDb(this.lista[2][i][j]):"",
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
                        onChanged: (value)=> infoAlmacenarValCart.agregar=['${this.lista[2][i][j]}',value]
                          
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap:null,
                  ),
                ),
              SizedBox(height:15),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          //SizedBox(height: 10,),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: usage1]
[image: usage2]

Comment: Probably not your problem, but do you really need a Theme Widget around *every* textfield? It should be sufficient to have it once, above your loop, since your theme doesn't change inside the loop.

Comment: @nvoigt Nice onservation. Then, i realized that when i use any FloatingactionButton dispose() never calls in my Screen() 

`floatingActionButton: Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
  children: [
    FloatingTextCode(),
    SizedBox(height: 15,),
    AddButtonFitosanidad(),
  ],
)`